# How to pass the values corretly from a bind function in a onChange event handler?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Field in a form, and want to send it to firebase everytime its change. Like this:

```
<center>
   <TextField
      type='number'
      value={this.props.game.home_result}
      onChange={this.props.homeScoreChangedHandler.bind(this, this.props.game)} 
   />
 </center>
```

But in my container, when I handle it, the values of the game is not being passed. Worst, my Event property its coming with a weird value, and my game property with the value of the Event.

```
homeScoreChangedHandler = async (event, game) => {
  let gameToBeUpdated = { ...game };
  gameToBeUpdated.away_result = event.target.value;
  await this.props.updateMatch(gameToBeUpdated);
}
```

On my homeScoreChangedHandler, the values of event and game are not being passed correctly. What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a lambda:

```
 onChange={(e,props.game)=>props.homeScoreChangedHandler(e, props.game)}
```